# [eyeshot]How can I add a new Viewport into a viewer

Tags: viewport, eyeshot

what is the best way to add a new viewport into the viewer with the same drawing?

Regards Jürgen

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Custom ViewportLayout source code sample](https://www.devdept.com/support/samples#customviewportlayout).

Here is the code extracted from the above sample

```
private static void InitializeViewportsByLayoutType(Design design, viewportLayoutType layout)
{
    int viewportsNumber;
    switch (layout)
    {
        case viewportLayoutType.SingleViewport:
            viewportsNumber = 1;
            break;
        case viewportLayoutType.TwoViewportsVertical:
        case viewportLayoutType.TwoViewportsHorizontal:
            viewportsNumber = 2;
            break;
        case viewportLayoutType.ThreeViewportsWithOneOnBottom:
        case viewportLayoutType.ThreeViewportsWithOneOnLeft:
        case viewportLayoutType.ThreeViewportsWithOneOnRight:
        case viewportLayoutType.ThreeViewportsWithOneOnTop:
            viewportsNumber = 3;
            break;
        case viewportLayoutType.FourViewports:
        case viewportLayoutType.Stacked:
            viewportsNumber = 4;
            break;
        default:
            viewportsNumber = 1;
            break;
    }

    if (design.Viewports.Count > viewportsNumber)
    {
        while (design.Viewports.Count > viewportsNumber)
            design.Viewports.RemoveAt(design.Viewports.Count - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (design.Viewports.Count < viewportsNumber)
        {
            design.Viewports.Add((Viewport)design.Viewports[0].Clone());
        }
    }

    // When changing the LayoutMode, the UpdateViewportsSizeAndLocation() method is called as well.
    design.LayoutMode = layout;
}
```